# Regex for min 8 characters and at least 1 number

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I'm looking for a regex for my JavaScript password function which checks that the user's password is at least 8 characters long with at least 1 number in it.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried.......? *edit:* [have a hoon on this online tester](http://regex101.com/), it'll teach you everything you need to know.

Comment: What kind of characters? Is the Thai alphabet acceptable?

Comment: You can just use `.length > 8` for the length being 8 or more characters.  And `.match(/[0-9]/).length > 0` for checking if there are numbers.

Comment: My knowledge of writing regular expressions is completely nada, so throughout my googling and regex generator tool usage, I couldn't manipulate the regex to fit these criteria.  Basically, I've tried a bunch of irrelevant solutions.

Comment: @Mash Use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for extra eliteness ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*\d).{8,}$/
```

> `(?=.*\d)` Asserts that a digit is anywhere within the string.
>
> `.{8,}` Asserts that the entire string is a composition of at least 8 "anything, except new line".

[View an online regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dD5bF4/1).

Comment: This regex nearly works for most use-cases, but it also matches strings that only have numbers. Is there a way, where we could also enforce at least 1 letter?

Comment: @lucbas add `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`: `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/`